# recover files after accidentally changing the partition table

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, files, data-recovery, clone

I have an internal drive of 500GB called /dev/sda that have nine partitions (sda1 to sda9).I also have an external hard drive of 1TB called /dev/sdb that have one partition called sdb1 in NTFS format, about 850 GB was used to store files (videos, music,pdf,etc.). In Ubuntu, I connect the external hard drive and then I used this command:

`sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=64K conv=noerror,sync status=progress`

To clone the internal hard drive to the external hard drive. But a few minutes after the cloning started, I realize that I was mistaken and I canceled the process by pressing ctrl+c then remove external hard drive. When I plug the external hard drive again it now contains nine partition like the internal hard drive, which means that I lost the partition that was containing 850 GB of my files. Please can you provide me a solution to recover the 850 GB of files.Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you copy the existing 1TB disk, so you have a backup in case restore attempts make things worse?  Testdisk might be able to see what's left of your files.  I'm not sure, but simply putting the original 1 partition might be a start (don't expect to see any files, the start of the filesystem is certainly gone). Google does test disk work on ntfs to see other attempts.

Comment: Whatever dd overwrote is gone. Your only recourse is your backups. If drive was gpt with backup gpt partition table at end of drive, you may be able to recover some data. If testdisk sees any files with deeper search immediately copy them. We have seen users who see files but do not then copy & never recover them. Testdisk also has photorec, but it takes forever to run, only recovers files by extension, so lots of work to rename files. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec Many with Windows say Windows tools work better but often not free.